Line Bundles on Elliptic Curves lift From Quotient
Suppose I have an elliptic curve $E$ and take its quotient by some finite group $G$. Is there some relation between the line bundles on $E$ and the line bundles on $E/G$? For example does every line bundle on $E$ come from some line bundle on $E/G$?

Have you tried the quotient by the standard involution, so that the quotient is the projective line?

I didn't consider that example thank you. What about the situation when $G$ acts by translations so the quotient is still an elliptic curve?

The pullbacks from $E/G$ are $G$-invariant. A simple example of a line bundle which is not $G$-invariant is $\mathcal{O}_E(P)$ where $P \in E$ is a point which is not fixed by $G$.
